# Iron Router, how to redirect to a newly created item?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have the following route made with Iron Router for a simple projects/tasks app:

```
Router.route('/tasks/:_id', {
  name: 'tasks.project',
  template: 'tasks',
  waitOn: function(){
    //subscribing to all user's projects and tasks
    return [Meteor.subscribe('userTasks'),Meteor.subscribe('userProjects')];
  },
  onAfterAction: function(){
    //Session var used to show only tasks assigned to the project _id
    Session.set('currentProject', this.params._id);
  }
});
```

When the user creates a new project, I want to redirect him to the corresponding page (/tasks/xxxxxxxxx). 
So, I created a method on the server and a simulation on the client like this:

```
//Server
Meteor.methods({
  createProject: function(){
    Projects.insert({/*some data*/}, function (error, result) {
    });
  }
});

//Client
Meteor.methods({
  createProject: function(){
    Projects.insert({/*some data*/}, function (error, result) {
      //Router.go does not work (jumps briefly to /tasks/xxxxxxxxx, and comes back) (I verifiedn result corresponds to the new project id)
      Router.go('tasks.project', {_id: result});
    });
  }
});
```

I am calling this method like this:

```
Template.tasks.events({
  'click .create-project': function(event, template){
    Meteor.call('createProject', function(error, result){
    });
  }
});
```

The Router.go function in client side insert does not work.
The only way I have found to make this work is to make the *server side* insert synchronous and put the `Router.go` in the method call callback. Like in this new version:

```
//Server
Meteor.methods({
  createProject: function(){
    //now synchronous
    var id = Projects.insert({/*some data*/});
    return id;
  }
});

//Client
Meteor.methods({
  createProject: function(){
    Projects.insert({/*some data*/}, function (error, result) {          
    });
  }
});
Template.tasks.events({
  'click .create-project': function(event, template){
    Meteor.call('createProject', function(error, result){
      Router.go('tasks.project', {_id: result});
    });
  }
});
```

But this redirection is subject to server latency, which I want to avoid. Considering that the new project document is immediately created in the client's collection thanks to the simulated method, shouldn't Iron Router be able to redirect in the first version of this code? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem comes from the difference between the _id generated for the fake client date and the real _id defined by the server. Indeed, the _id is generated using the Meteor.uuid function which generates a random id every time it's called.

Thus, when you receive the server response and your database is synced, the fake Project that was generated no longer exists and has been replaced by the real new Project (which has been saved on the server) with a different _id. So, when this happens, your route points to a Project that no longer exist.

You should then maybe accept some waiting time for your user or at least reroute your user to the right url when you get the server response. The code would thus be :

```
//Server
Meteor.methods({
  createProject: function(){
    return Projects.insert({/*some data*/});
  }
});

//Client
Meteor.methods({
  createProject: function(){
    Projects.insert({/*some data*/}, function (error, result) {
      //Router.go does not work (jumps briefly to /tasks/xxxxxxxxx, and comes back) (I verifiedn result corresponds to the new project id)
      Router.go('tasks.project', {_id: result});
    });
  }
});
```

And your event

```
Template.tasks.events({
  'click .create-project': function(event, template){
    Meteor.call('createProject', function(error, result){
      Router.go('tasks.project', {_id: result});
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I also thought first that that was the reason, but when doing console.log() on both insert results (client & server side) I get the exact same id. When Router.go is jumping to /tasks/xxxxxxxx and coming back it is actually jumping to the right id which does not change.